# How can I get a timeout exception on an android streaming socket connection?

Tags: java, android, sockets, timeout

I've been writing an application that requires a connection to a TCP server.
I have been trying to get this section of the code to give off some sort of exception when it can't connect to the server-side port.
I know for a fact that it can't connect because I've shut down my server and the port is blocked.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void run()
{
    mRun = true;
    try
    {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        try
        {
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

....

In any case, my code ends up being stuck on the new Socket() constructor, and it doesn't throw any IO exceptions.
So far I've tried

```
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

but it has made no difference.

Any ideas on possible actions I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO_TIMEOUT setting only affects reading from the socket, not the initial connection. You can make the connection time out by creating an unconnected socket and then using the `connect` method that permits a `timeout` parameter:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, SERVERPORT), timeout);
```

Comment: This seems to work. Can't believe I didn't notice I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIpAddress, serverPort), timeout);
```